# AJAX I don't receive any response from the server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using two modals forms in one page, one for login and another for register. From login form you can access the register one. I am trying to show an error based on what I echo without reload the page. Instead of echo I tried to return or print,but I got nothing.I don't receive anything from the server. In console.log show me only "Message".

Here is my code:

register.php

```
if ($count == 0) {
    if ($check == 1)
        $query = "INSERT INTO..
    elseif ($check == 2)
        $query = "INSERT INTO..
    else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO .. 
    }

    if ($db->query($query)) {
        echo "1";
    } else {
        echo "2";
    }
} else {
    echo "3";
}
```

My jS

```
$("#register").on('submit',function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
/*var $form=$(this);*/
$.ajax({
    url : 'register.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : $('#id02').serialize(),
    success : function (data) {
        console.log("Message:"+data);
        $('#error-reg').text("Success").css('color', 'green');
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        if(msg=="2") $('#error-reg').html('Error while registering.Please try again');
        if(msg=="3") $('#error-reg').html('The username already exists.');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: comment everything inside register.php and just do a simple echo to check if your ajax can reach that page

Comment: you are sending $_POST values now where you are receiving them ?

Comment: You are not using the data in your php code received from the ajax call (the $_POST array).

Comment: edit you success portoin. i explain it. show my answer

Comment: Ajax can reach the page and it enters in 'success' and show the message 'Success'. The problem is that data is empty. It doesn't show anything. If i have an error doesn't show one of the error.

Answer (score 1):

try your **error: function** with below code to check in details

```
    error: function (xhr, err) {
       alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
       alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
success : function (data) 
{
    if(data==1)
    {
       $('#error-reg').text("Success").css('color', 'green');
    }
    else if(data==2)
    {
       $('#error-reg').html('Error while registering.Please try; 
    }
    else if(data==3)
    {
        $('#error-reg').html('The username already exists.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It shows me 'Success' even if I have an error and the username exists and in mydatabase doesn't insert.

Comment: what you want extactly?

Comment: I want to show me the message "The username already exists" in that div if that username exists or if I have another error "Error while registering.Please try again". In other posts, I saw that you can echo something and verify in Ajax and based on that you can show the error. Also, when I make console.log I think I should see the data received, but in my case is it empty.